# “Ex Machina” versus “Deus Ex Machina”

Tags: meaning, latin

I have recently watched a movie called *Ex Machina*. I searched for the meaning, but *Deus Ex Machina* was the closest to this title.

There certainly must be a relation but can someone please tell me what that might be?

Comment: Did the film you watched give you any clues?

Comment: "Ex machina" means "out of the machine". Sounds like a fitting title according to what I read about the movie.

Comment: *Deus ex machina* means "god from the machine" and refers to the Greek (that's right, it's a Latin phrase referring to a Greek practice; no hate mail, please) theatrical practice of resolving dramas by having whatever god presided over the goings-on be literally lowered on a rope from a crane to a point above the stage. What that has to do with the *Ex Machina* film I have no idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the interpretation of a movie title.

Comment: @Robusto The various English dictionaries give this noun a completely different meaning differing form the description of a stage penomenon. Given that it's a dictionary term, I don't think it's off topic here.

Comment: @Araucaria: The question is about what the movie title means.

Comment: @Robusto Is it in Japanese? The title, I mean?

Comment: @Araucaria: Take a wild guess.

Comment: @Robusto So it's a title being Used in the English Language?

Comment: @Robusto So I just mean that it seems kinda like a straightforwardly EL&U question :) [even though this English Language appears in a film title ... ]

Comment: This seems like a good discussion question on some movie site. Obviously the author (and/or marketers) are somewhat educated enough to come up with a title that is exotic sounding and provocative. If they meant 'Deus ex Machina' (a literary trope for bringing in a plot changer out of nowhere (the eagles in Tolkien)),they would have used that and it would have been an inappropriate title. 'Ex Machina' probably was intended to mean something more like 'out of machines ... [we can make something human-like but we're not sure but sexy lady for nerds]'.

Comment: Nobody pointing out how "ex machina" as used here is also a kind of cross-language pun? By the end of the movie, she's arguably an "ex-machine"?

Answer (score 7):

The expression originated as 'deus ex machina' from a Latin translation as shown below and its modern meaning refer to a literary/artistic device used to solve apparently irresolvable situations ( as if by divine intervention). 'Ex machina' as such just refers  to its original expression. In the movie, the scientist Nathan appears to be the 'Deus ex machina'. I think there is also a play on words in the title which refers to  the 'humanoid' Eva which is not longer a 'machine' but very close to a human being.

[Deus ex machina](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=deus%20&searchmode=none): (Etymonline)

> - 1690s, from Modern Latin translation of Greek a̲p̲o̲ mekhanes theos, literally "the god from the machina," the device by which "gods" were suspended over the stage in Greek theater.  The fem. is dea ex machina.

[Deus ex machina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina): (Wikipedia)

> - The term has evolved to mean a plot device whereby a seemingly unsolvable problem is suddenly and abruptly resolved by the contrived and unexpected intervention of some new event, character, ability or object. Depending on how it is done, it can be intended to move the story forward when the writer has "painted himself into a corner" and sees no other way out, to surprise the audience, to bring the tale to a happy ending, or as a comedic device.